# Magmi Attribute Set Importer v0.0.2 - Attributes not appearing on product admin page after import

Tags: import, magmi

I am trying to Import a whole bunch of products with Magmi which is working fine however I need to import custom attributes for each product. To do this I am using Magmi Attribute Set Importer v0.0.2 where I have created 3 csv spreadsheets;

- My product list which is working fine
- My Attribute csv which creates all the attributes I need
- and my attributeset csv which links the previously created attributes with the required group

After running the import I can see that the attributes have been created and exist in the correct attribute set/group.
The problem that I am having is when I go to a product page for a product using that attribute set, I cannot see the newly created attribute and cannot change its value.

Here are the data fields I am using to import the attribute:

```
attribute_code,frontend_label,is_visible_on_front
thickness,Thickness,1
```

Comment: Have you checked with your attribute id are matching with store and csv ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have created the attribute in magento backend and by doing inspect element on newly created attribute, Take name from opening in `add products` and give proper name in magmi csv. and make sure your csv is in text format while uploading. you can directly give name of the attribute in csv file.

please check following image on selecting name of attributes in magmi.

[image]

Just make sure about name and it's options in magento backend's attribute tab.